# navigator.language not recognized correctly in app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, operators

This is my controller

```
app.controller('languagesCtrl', function($scope) {
  var lang = window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage;
  if (lang === 'it' || 'it-it' || 'it-IT') {
    $scope.showcase = 'Vetrina';
    $scope.products = 'Prodotti';
    $scope.cta = 'Nuova collezione strumenti';
  } else {
    $scope.showcase = 'Showcase';
    $scope.products = 'Products';
    $scope.cta = 'Check out new products!';
  }
});
```

and even if I'm SURE my navigator.language isn't 'it-IT' (checked [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp)), my angular-based website doesn't use what's inside in the else's brackets.

Comment: It breaks that controller, somehow related with the fact that I'm using coffeescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is always going to be true, the way you have `||` operator used.

When expression evaluated

1st part (`lang === 'it'`) it might be `true` or `false`, suppose it is false.

then expression becomes like `(false || 'it-it' || 'it-IT')` which will always return going to return next expression value, here it would be `it-it` in this case, so anyways if condition is going to get satisfied.

Change it to below.

```
if (lang === 'it' || lang === 'it-it' || lang === 'it-IT')
```

OR event simplified.

```
if (['it','it-it','it-IT'].indexOf(lang) > -1)
```

Comment: Yay it works :D bad operators, my bad :P will accept in 5 minutes sir!

Answer (score 0):

**ES6 solves this beautifully**

I am just putting this here incase people in future stumble upon this. Use `includes()` for ES6.

`['it','it-it','it-IT'].includes(language)`

**ES5 Solution**

This stuff always used to get me, until I realised, I am using multiple OR comparisons incorrectly.  So I did this to make it more readable.

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    return this.indexOf(obj) > -1;
};
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
var language = $window.navigator.language.

if (['it','it-it','it-IT']].contains(language)) {
    alert('yes');
}
```

This is more readable. Of course, if you are using underscore.js, they have the following helper.

`_.contains([], search)`

Comment: Thank to you too, but I'll stick to correct my wrong comparisons :D